# Building Android webview on Kubuntu 20.04 (not Ubuntu)

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, android-webview

I am trying to build Android Webview on Kubuntu 20.04.3. But when I try to execute `build/install-build-deps.sh`, I get the following output:

```
Hit:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [40,7 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [66,2 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2 464 B]
Fetched 223 kB in 1s (372 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
Building apt package list.
Skipping debugging symbols.
Skipping 32-bit libraries.
Skipping ARM cross toolchain.
Skipping NaCl, NaCl toolchain, NaCl ports dependencies.
Finding missing packages...
Packages required:  apache2-bin binutils binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf binutils-mips64el-linux-gnuabi64 binutils-mipsel-linux-gnu bison bzip2 cdbs curl dbus-x11 devscripts dpkg-dev elfutils fakeroot flex git-core gperf lib32gcc-s1 lib32stdc++6 libapache2-mod-php7.4 libasound2 libasound2-dev libatk1.0-0 libatspi2.0-0 libatspi2.0-dev libbluetooth-dev libbrlapi0.7 libbrlapi-dev libbz2-1.0 libbz2-dev libc6 libc6-dev libc6-i386 libcairo2 libcairo2-dev libcap2 libcap-dev libcups2 libcups2-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libdrm2 libdrm-dev libelf-dev libevdev2 libevdev-dev libexpat1 libffi7 libffi-dev libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgbm1 libgbm-dev libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-dev libinput10 libinput-dev libjpeg-dev libkrb5-dev libnspr4 libnspr4-dev libnss3 libnss3-dev libpam0g libpam0g-dev libpango-1.0-0 libpci3 libpci-dev libpcre3 libpixman-1-0 libpng16-16 libpulse0 libpulse-dev libsctp-dev libspeechd2 libspeechd-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libstdc++6 libudev1 libudev-dev libuuid1 libva-dev libvulkan1 libvulkan-dev libwayland-egl1-mesa libwww-perl libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxau6 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon-dev libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence-dev libxslt1-dev libxss-dev libxt-dev libxtst6 libxtst-dev locales mesa-common-dev openbox p7zip patch perl php7.4-cgi pkg-config python2-dev python-crypto python-is-python2 python-numpy python-openssl python-psutil python-setuptools python-yaml rpm ruby snapcraft subversion uuid-dev wdiff x11-utils xcompmgr xz-utils zip zlib1g

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
...

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libasound2-dev : Depends: libasound2 (= 1.2.2-2.1)
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is to be installed
 libcairo2-dev : Depends: libfontconfig1-dev (>= 2.2.95) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libfreetype6-dev (>= 2.1.10) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libpng-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libcups2-dev : Depends: libcupsimage2-dev (= 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libdrm-dev : Depends: libdrm2 (= 2.4.101-2) but 2.4.105-3~20.04.2 is to be installed
              Depends: libdrm-intel1 (= 2.4.101-2) but 2.4.105-3~20.04.2 is to be installed
              Depends: libdrm-radeon1 (= 2.4.101-2) but 2.4.105-3~20.04.2 is to be installed
              Depends: libdrm-nouveau2 (= 2.4.101-2) but 2.4.105-3~20.04.2 is to be installed
              Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (= 2.4.101-2) but 2.4.105-3~20.04.2 is to be installed
 libelf-dev : Depends: zlib1g-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libevdev-dev : Depends: libevdev2 (= 1.9.0+dfsg-1) but 1.9.0+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
 libgbm-dev : Depends: libgbm1 (= 20.0.4-2ubuntu1) but 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5 is to be installed
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.3) but 2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.4 is to be installed
                  Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.3)
                  Depends: libmount-dev (>= 2.28) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: zlib1g-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libglu1-mesa-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                             libgl-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libgtk-3-dev : Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (= 3.24.18-1ubuntu1) but 3.24.20-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libepoxy-dev (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libfontconfig1-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.40.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.41) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgtk-3-0 (= 3.24.18-1ubuntu1) but 3.24.20-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libinput-dev : Depends: libinput10 (= 1.15.5-1) but 1.15.5-1ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
                Depends: libwacom-dev (>= 0.20) but it is not going to be installed
 libpam0g-dev : Depends: libpam0g (= 1.3.1-5ubuntu4) but 1.3.1-5ubuntu4.2 is to be installed
 libpci-dev : Depends: libpci3 (= 1:3.6.4-1) but 1:3.6.4-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
              Depends: zlib1g-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libpulse-dev : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8) but 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11 is to be installed
                Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8) but 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11 is to be installed
 mesa-common-dev : Depends: libgl-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libglx-dev but it is not going to be installed
 uuid-dev : Depends: libuuid1 (= 2.34-0.1ubuntu9) but 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1 is to be installed

You will have to install the above packages yourself.
```

So I see some packages are not installed... Is there a way to configure this properly?